# How can I slice elements of one Pandas dataframe column by different values?

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a "dirty" csv file loaded into a Pandas dataframe. One column "Name" sometimes comes with prefixes (e.g. "(3.)" before the actual name).

I understand the taxonomy of this prefix and know how to find the indexes from which onwards I would like to keep the rest of the string:

```
df["Indexes"]= df["Name"].str.find(')')
```

But: How do I cut evertying up to that index?

For example, if "Name" is "(3.) Peter", I want it to become "Peter".

Hypothetically, I would want to use slice. My problem is that the value by which I need to slice varies per row. -- below would work if the prefix had always length 4, which it doesn't (sometimes no prefix, sometimes length 5).

```
pd.Series(df["Name"]).str.slice(4)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: If you know the pattern, you could use `.str.replace()`. See [regex-replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the pattern, you can use `extract` to get the clean name:

```py
# The "dirty" CSV
string = """
(3.) Peter
(10.) David
Jane
(100.) Mary Wether
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), header=None, names=['Name'])

# Clean it
df['CleanName'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r'(\(.*\) )?(?P<Name>.+?)( \(.*\))?')['Name']
```

Result:

```
                 Name    CleanName
0          (3.) Peter        Peter
1         (10.) David        David
2                Jane         Jane
3  (100.) Mary Wether  Mary Wether
```

Head over to [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/v73FNV/) for an explanation of the regex pattern.

Comment: Cool, works! But how does that work when the identfier comes after the name sequence? If the name is `Peter (3.)`, then `?=\(.+\)` works for me. But how do you do it when the `(..)` is missing entirely?

Comment: See my edited answer. Be careful though: regex is not the answer to every pattern. Sometimes the patterns get so complex that you can't easily fit them all into a single regex. If you find the regex too hard to write, it's a good sign that you need to break it into several regexes or use a different processing strategy